# Why less command in tmux show output not on beginning?

Tags: tmux, less-unix

Usually `less` command show output from beginning of the page (terminal emulator visible part).

But in tmux case it show output in the same place as `echo` command - not  on the top - on the free space.

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: which terminal do you use? pls report `echo $TERM` output in tmux.

Comment: lxterminal
debian 8.2

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/492